# CUTE unit test not recognizing thrown exception

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Using the [CUTE unit test framework](http://cute-test.com/) I have the following classes:

```
const std::size_t COARSE_MODEL_COUNT = 4;

class ModelType
{
   public:

      explicit ModelType(std::size_t aModelNumber) : theModelNumber(aModelNumber){}

      virtual operator size_t(){ return theModelNumber; }

   protected:

      std::size_t theModelNumber;
};

class CoarseModelType : public ModelType
{
   public:

      explicit CoarseModelType(std::size_t aModelNumber) : ModelType(aModelNumber)
      {
         if (COARSE_MODEL_COUNT <= aModelNumber)
         {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid model number selected for \
                                        this model type.");
         }
      }
};
```

with the following unit test:

```
void ModelTypeTest::testCoarseModelConstructor()
{
   //greater than test
   ASSERT_THROWS(CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT+1), std::invalid_argument);

   //equal to
   ASSERT_THROWS(CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT), std::invalid_argument);
}
```

If I comment out the second `ASSERT_THROWS` the unit test passes correctly.  If I leave it in it fails.  I would think that using the `<=` operator on a `std::size_t` type would recognize the `==` component but it's not.  The `ASSERT_THROWS` is a macro.

We're on Linux using `gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)`.  Is there some sort of implicit conversion or something going on that I'm not aware of?  We're all scratching our heads on this one.

**Edit:**

The following does throw an error within the unit test and is registered as an error rather than a fail.  The exception is thrown before the second `ASSERT_THROWS` statement has a chance to fail:

```
void ModelTypeTest::testCoarseModelConstructor()
{
   //greater than test
   ASSERT_THROWS(CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT+1), std::invalid_argument);

   if(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT <= COARSE_MODEL_COUNT){
      throw std::invalid_argument("wtf");
   }

   //equal to
   ASSERT_THROWS(CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT), std::invalid_argument);
}
```

So this is an issue with CUTE.  I just don't know the how or why in regards to the macro interaction with the constructor code.

Comment: Could you show us the `ASSERT_THROWS` macro, or better still expand it in place in `testCoarseModel`? I have a hunch it's not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @Beta from the CUTE website: `ASSERT_THROWSM(msg, code, exc)
ASSERT_THROWS(code, exc)

    Fail if code does not throw exception exc.`

Comment: Instead of `CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT)`, try `CoarseModelType dummy(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT)` and see what happens.

Comment: P.S. you can have gcc preprocess the code without compiling it by means of the `-E` option. That way it'll expand the macros in place.

Comment: @Beta put down that as an answer so I can +1 it and accept.  (The dummy thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Ahem) I think the `ASSERT_THROWS` macro is doing something you're not aware of. Instead of

```
CoarseModelType(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT)
```

try

```
CoarseModelType dummy(COARSE_MODEL_COUNT)
```

and see what happens. The first is an odd way to invoke the constructor, and a clumsy macro might turn it into something that the compiler interprets differently.

(Note: you can use `gcc -E` to preprocess the source code without compiling it, expanding macros in place so that you can see what they're doing.)

Comment: I'm a firm believer in credit where credit due.  I never claim someone else's solution or work and I sure as hell don't want the solver to go unrewarded or recognized.

Comment: @wheaties: (It occurs to me that my last comment could be taken the wrong way. I meant it as a sardonic joke, not a criticism; my previous workplace was a political arena wherein credit-thieves and parasites thrived at the expense of those who actually solved problems. With your attitude you wouldn't have fared any better in that snakepit than I did.)

Comment: Joke well received.  We're software engineers.  We know exactly what you mean (unfortunately.)